# How to create new column based on top and bottom parts of single dataframe in PANDAS?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have merged two dataframes having same column names. Is there a easy way to get another column of mean of these two appended dataframes?

Maybe code explains it better.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[10,20,30,40]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.2,2.2,3.2,4.2],'b':[10.2,20.2,30.2,40.2]})

df = df1.append(df2)
print(df)

df['a_mean'] = ???

     a     b
0  1.0  10.0
1  2.0  20.0
2  3.0  30.0
3  4.0  40.0
0  1.2  10.2
1  2.2  20.2
2  3.2  30.2
3  4.2  40.2
```

How to create a new column a_mean with values
[1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1] effectively ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['a_mean'] = np.tile( (df1.a.to_numpy() + df2.a.to_numpy())/2, 2)
```

As per the comments, there is already a great answer by Anky, but to extend this method you can do this:

```
df['a_mean2'] = np.tile( (df.iloc[0: len(df)//2].a.to_numpy() + df.iloc[len(df)//2:].a.to_numpy())/2, 2)
```

Update:

```
df['a_mean3'] = np.tile(df.a.to_numpy().reshape(2,-1).mean(0), 2)
```

Outptut

```
print(df)
     a     b  a_mean2  a_mean  a_mean3
0  1.0  10.0      1.1     1.1      1.1
1  2.0  20.0      2.1     2.1      2.1
2  3.0  30.0      3.1     3.1      3.1
3  4.0  40.0      4.1     4.1      4.1
0  1.2  10.2      1.1     1.1      1.1
1  2.2  20.2      2.1     2.1      2.1
2  3.2  30.2      3.1     3.1      3.1
3  4.2  40.2      4.1     4.1      4.1
```

Answer (score 1):

**`melt()`**

```
df=df.assign(a_mean=df1.add(df2).div(2).melt().value)
```

Or taking only `df`, you can do:

```
df=df.assign(a_mean=df.groupby(df.index)['a'].mean())
```

---

```
     a     b  a_mean
0  1.0  10.0     1.1
1  2.0  20.0     2.1
2  3.0  30.0     3.1
3  4.0  40.0     4.1
0  1.2  10.2     1.1
1  2.2  20.2     2.1
2  3.2  30.2     3.1
3  4.2  40.2     4.1
```

Comment: What to do if I don't know df1 and df2 but only know df and want to create new column from top/bottom halves?

Comment: @MilkyWay007 sorry I didn't get that , can you briefly explain that

Comment: Lets say we have df with above values. From top and bottom half of this dataframe how to create new column like above?

Comment: @MilkyWay007 you mean `df=df.assign(a_mean=df.groupby(df.index)['a'].mean())` ?